# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied when running applet on browser

Tags: java, applet, signed

I am getting the following error when trying to run an applet in a browser. The applet in question contains file access code in it:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getenv.RGENGINEJAVA)
>    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.System.getenv(Unknown Source)
>    at com.socp.components.SOCPMapViewer.bootstrapArcobjectsJar(SOCPMapViewer.java:668)
>    at com.socp.components.SOCPMapViewer.init(SOCPMapViewer.java:130)
>    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getenv.RGSENGINEJAVA)

The applet works fine when invoked from the Elipse IDE but when I use an HTML file to run it in a browser it gives the above shown error. Please help me to resolve this issue. Tell me how I can grant the following permission file in the HTML context:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html